# What can you do with Writing Python using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I added the Python project to IntelliJ IDEA.
What is the use of these options at creation time?
What can they do?
[options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fukDs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

virtualenv is used to manage Python packages for different projects. Using virtualenv allows you to avoid installing Python packages globally which could break system tools or other projects. You can install virtualenv using pip. If you wanna learn more you can go through this article well explained [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-use-a-virtual-environment-for-every-python-project-c17dab3b0fd0)

Answer (score 0):

For the environment is what you install on your pc (python instance) suppose you have python 3.9 then by default your environment is python3.9 and here you can use already existing environment or a new one ( since you can download more than one version of python 3.0 3.1 3.9 ) for example.

With respect to environment type is what you will be using for example to download packages, suppose you want to choose COND or PIP or whatever.